# Python 3 unable to shorten this code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to shorten the following block of code
but i don't know how

**Posted on pastebin because it is 70 lines:**
https://pastebin.com/g2P8Lpbd

The intended function of the code is to 
print out a heart shaped grid, which it does.

Comment: 70 lines should be ok to post, and be easier for people here.  Which bit is slowest, and needs optimising?

Comment: sorry i meant shorten

Comment: It would be nice to know the intent of what you were doing as well. What does this code need to do?

Comment: Did you know you can place a loop *inside* another loop?

Answer (score 2):

So there are a few things going on with the loops that need some work. You essentially have lots of blocks that look like this:

```
var2= 0
var = 1
print()
for i in range(9):
    print(grid[var][var2],end=' ')
    var2= var2+1
```

Where `var` and `var2` are controlling which element in the list of lists gets printed out. However, you're using `i` in the `for` loop, when you could be using that to get the list elements:

```
for element in grid[var]:
   print(element, end=' ')
```

You can also nest loops inside each other, meaning you can replace all of that existing code with:

```
for outer in grid:
   for element in outer:
       print(element, end=' ')
```

Or, even shorter:

```
for outer in grid:
    print("".join(outer))
```

Comment: Great answer! This should be accepted

The last section is the way I would have done it, no need to keep track of indexes of lists, you just need to join the rows, and print each of them.

Comment: Actually there is a oneliner: `print("\n".join([" ".join(row) for row in grid]), end='')`

Comment: True, but possibly too much in one line to understand if the OP is having trouble with loops.